# Visual C++ 2008: Finding the cause of slow link times

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

I have a legacy C++ project that takes an annoyingly long time to build (several minutes, even for small incremental changes), and I found most of the time was spent linking.

The project is already using precompiled headers and incremental compilation.
I have enabled the "/time" command line parameter in the hope I would get more details about what is slowing the linker, and got the following output:

```
1>Linking...
1>  MD Merge: Total time = 59.938s
1>  Generate Transitions: Total time = 0.500s
1>  MD Finalize: Total time = 7.328s
1>Pass 1: Interval #1, time = 71.718s
1>Pass 2: Interval #2, time = 8.969s
1>Final: Total time = 80.687s
1>Final: Total time = 80.953s
```

Is there a way to get more details about each of these steps? 
For example, I would like to find if they are spending most time linking to a specific .lib or .obj file.

Also, is there any documentation that explains what each of these steps do?

Comment: Just for info, how many .cpp files are we talking about here ? For funny reference, we had an application a few years ago which took 12h to link (yep, a humongous library). Thankfully it's been splitted up in a few dozens of components and the hardware is better now ;)

Comment: 180 files spread across 10 projects + dependencies on 8 external .lib files (MFC + other proprietary libraries); so that's a reasonable amount of files in my opinion. But still, the structure may be improved by splitting some projects.
(12h that's awful, how did you manage to get any work done?)

Comment: Whcich version? Do you have Link Time Code Generation or Profiler Guided Optimizations enabled?

Comment: @peterchen: Visual Studio 2008 SP1, C++/CLI with .Net 3.5.
I did not have either options enabled. I tried enabling Link Time Code Generation to see what kind of difference it would make, but the linker failed with an "out of memory" error (maybe there's something to investigate there....)
As I understand these options, they would usually make linking slower, as the linker spends more time doing optimizations, is that right?

Comment: @ckarras: Yes. For a largish project with /LTCG, I'd say 80 seconds is not bad - since this means the majority of optimizations runs during link. I have zero experience with CLI, though. An OOM during link sounds really bad, assuming that you have a decently powerful machine. Hanging out at the VC++ team blog might help - I've seen the guys diagnose various very specific problems in the comments section. Or try reporting the OOM at MS Connect.

Comment: have you figured out anything? Build perfromance is a pet topic for me.

Comment: @peterchen Not yet. I've resorted to another solution for now: 
create .vcproj/.exe files that represent subsets of the application (one subset for each area of the application I'm working on). These .vcproj files don't reference other projects or .lib files, instead they recompile the .cpp files.

So I still have a long link time when I want to compile the whole application, but at least I can work on small units at a reasonable pace.

A nice side effect of this is that it's a good way to start breaking dependencies, which are a big problem in this application.

Answer (score 4):

The "MD Merge" step is looking for and merging duplicate string literals and other duplicated data. Note that the time required to do this is O(n^2) over the number of string literals that you have, so I once had a similar problem where a header file with ~10K string literals would take 5 min to link.

Adding the linker flag `/OPT:NOICF` may help. Alternately, examine why you have so many literals to fold.

Comment: Why is it O(N²)? It seems like it would be O(n log n)?

Comment: From the docs - `The optional iterations parameter specifies the number of times to traverse the symbols for duplicates. The default number of iterations is two. Additional iterations may locate more duplicates that are uncovered through folding in the previous iteration.`

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully someone from the vs dev team would see this and be able to comment, maybe post a link to their forum/blog and ope for the best?

First random theory that comes to me would be to investigate how much in-header code is generated, such that "phase 1" would have such a lot of work to do eliminating dupes. I am specifically thinking of template or macro or old-style constant declarations. These would also be aggrevated by inclusion into a common precompiled header as I have seen very often wihh naive setup for windows/mfc/STL using projects.

Good luck, it would be great to hear if you find something particular that was bad.